# STRIPE + TypeScript : TypeError: stripe_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: typescript, jestjs, stripe-payments

I'm running some testings of Stripe code in my TypeScript MicroService :

```
process.env.STRIPE_KEY = 'sk_test_...............';
import Stripe from 'stripe';
export const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_KEY!, {
  apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
});
```

However I keep getting that the constructor is not defined :

```
 **TypeError: stripe_1.default is not a constructor**

 1 | import Stripe from 'stripe';
> 2 | export const stripe = new Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_KEY!, {
    |                       ^
  3 |   apiVersion: '2020-03-02',
  4 | });
  5 |

  at Object.<anonymous> (src/stripe.ts:2:23)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/new.ts:14:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app.ts:6:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/__test__/newNoMocks.test.ts:3:1)
```

**Package JSON:**

```
"dependencies": {    
    "@types/cookie-session": "^2.0.40",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.22",
    "cookie-session": "^1.4.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.18",
    "mongoose-update-if-current": "^1.4.0",
    "stripe": "^8.81.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  },
```

Any idea what might cause this ?

**TSCONFIG:**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./build",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    // "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    // "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    /* Advanced Options */
    ,"forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

**EDIT #2 - 02-08-20 - The Test:**

**new.test.ts :**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from '../../app';
import { Order } from '../../models/order';
import { OrderStatus } from '@myNPMpackage/common';
import { stripe } from '../../stripe';
import { Payment } from '../../models/payment';

it('No Mock - returns a 201 with valid inputs', async () => {
  const userId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
  const price = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
  // create order
  const order = Order.build({
    id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(),
    userId,
    version: 0,
    price,
    status: OrderStatus.Created,
  });

  await order.save();

  // send API Request
  await request(app)
    .post('/api/payments')
    .set('Cookie', global.signin(userId))
    .send({
      orderId: order.id,
      token: 'tok_visa', // valid token
    })
    .expect(201);

  const stripeCharges = await stripe.charges.list({ limit: 50 });
  const stripeCharge = stripeCharges.data.find((charge) => {
    return charge.amount === price * 100; // *100 because we move from Dollars to Cents
  });
  expect(stripeCharge).toBeDefined();
  expect(stripeCharge!.currency).toEqual('usd');

  // Test Payment
  const payment = await Payment.findOne({
    orderId: order.id,
    stripeId: stripeCharge!.id,
  });

  expect(payment).not.toBeNull();
});
```

**The Router**

```
router.post(
  '/api/payments',
  requireAuth,
  [body('token').not().isEmpty(), body('orderId').not().isEmpty()],
  validateRequest,
  async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const { token, orderId } = req.body;
    const order = await Order.findById(orderId);
    if (!order) {
      throw new NotFoundError();
    }
    if (order.userId !== req.currentUser!.id) {
      throw new NotAuthorizedError();
    }

    if (order.status === OrderStatus.Cancelled) {
      throw new BadRequestError('Cannot pay for a cancelled order!');
    }

    // Call Stripe and charge Credit Cards
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      currency: 'usd',
      amount: order.price * 100, // given in USD , we need to convert to CENTS
      source: token,
    });

    // Create a payment
    const payment = Payment.build({
      orderId,
      stripeId: charge.id,
    });

    // Save the payment
    await payment.save();

    // Call publisher
    await new PaymentCreatedPublisher(natsWrapper.client).publish({
      id: payment.id,
      orderId: payment.orderId,
      stripeId: payment.stripeId,
    });

    res.status(201).send(payment);
  }
);
```

**app.ts :**

```
import express from 'express';
import 'express-async-errors';
import { json } from 'body-parser';
import cookieSession from 'cookie-session';
import { errorHandler, NotFoundError, currentUser } from '@myNPMpackage/common';
import { createChargeRouter } from './routes/new';

const app = express();
app.set('trust proxy', true); // express is aware that it's behind a proxy inginx and it should trust traffic from that proxy
app.use(json());
app.use(
  cookieSession({
    signed: false,
    secure: false, // this one means - don't send cookie if the request is not HTTPS (Secured) , HTTP request won't receive the cookie
    // secure : process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test'
  })
);

app.use(currentUser);
app.use(createChargeRouter);

app.all('*', async (req, res, next) => {
  // next(new NotFoundError());
  throw new NotFoundError();
});

app.use(errorHandler);

export { app };
```

Comment: Care to share your `tsconfig` ?

Comment: It looks like the error occurs during testing? If so, what is your setup to transplie the test though?

Comment: @tmhao2005: Yes during running `Jest` , but why ? what's the problem with the Constructor of Stripe ? This `const stripe = new Stripe(.........);` Does not work!

Comment: I’m not to sure but I’m keen to know the way you transpile your code. Are u using ts-jest too? Can I see your full test + jest config?

Comment: Since I don't seen anything wrong with the library which exports `Stripe` class as default export which you can init as class. Otherwise, you did configure something wrong.

Comment: @ tmhao2005 : I've edited the original post  ,thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219082/discussion-between-tmhao2005-and-jan).

Comment: Can you also post your jest config + cli you run your test as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are taking [Stephen Grider's microservices course](https://www.udemy.com/course/microservices-with-node-js-and-react/).

Did you rename `src/__mocks__/stripe.ts` to `src/__mocks__/stripe.ts.old`?

This looks like TS is working against the mock stripe module, not the *real* stripe module. Make sure to remove (or rename) `src/__mocks__/stripe.ts`.

If the mock stripe filename is the same as the module, then jest will use the mock stripe. Note, this applies *even if you remove*  `jest.mock('../../stripe');`

From [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks):

> When a manual mock exists for a given module, Jest's module system will use that module when explicitly calling jest.mock('moduleName'). However, when automock is set to true, the manual mock implementation will be used instead of the automatically created mock, even if jest.mock('moduleName') is not called. To opt out of this behavior you will need to explicitly call jest.unmock('moduleName') in tests that should use the actual module implementation.

Comment: Thanks brother , this one really pissed me off :)

Comment: I made the same error. It didn't sound like it was mandatory. I learned the hard way, reading the docs. :-)