# failed mock stripe on lambda function : TypeError: stripe_1.default is not a constructor

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, stripe-payments, ts-jest

i want to mock stripe sdk on lambda function, this is how i create instance of stripe on config

```
export const stripe = new Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
  typescript: true,
  maxNetworkRetries: 2,
});
```

and this is how i use the stripe instance on my lambda function

```
import { stripe, STRIPE_TEST_USERS } from '../config';

await stripe.invoices.retrieve(id)
```

and this is what i got

```
  TypeError: stripe_1.default is not a constructor

  36 | });
  37 |
> 38 | export const stripe = new Stripe(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
     |                       ^
  39 |   apiVersion: '2020-08-27',
  40 |   typescript: true,
  41 |   maxNetworkRetries: 2,
```

dont get me wrong , i have tried all thing i can do, i have tried this method

1st

```
 jest.mock("stripe", () => {
      return jest.fn().mockImplementation(()=> {
        return {
          invoices: {
            retrieve: () =>jest.fn(),
          },
        };
      });
    });
```

2nd

```
jest.mock('stripe', () =>
   jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    invoices: {
      retrieve: () => jest.fn()
   },
  }))
 );
```

3rd

```
jest.mock('stripe', () => ({
  ...jest.mock('stripe'),
  Stripe: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
    return {
      invoices: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          retrieve: jest.fn(),
        };
      }),
    };
  }),
}));
```

but none of those work, any solution?

Comment: Looking at code snippet examples in the Stripe API reference docs (https://stripe.com/docs/api/authentication?lang=node) for Node.js, I think the `new` keyword is the issue.  Have you tried removing it?

Comment: i have not tried it yet and i cant change the code because its legacy code and in another repo its work using 2nd way, but i dont know why this not work when i try to mock it in lambda function @RyanM

Comment: Sorry I just saw the `ts-jest` tag.  After doing some searching specific to TypeScript and Stripe instantiation I found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63208439/stripe-typescript-typeerror-stripe-1-default-is-not-a-constructor

Take a look and see if this helps.

Comment: i have read it, but thats not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can use this, u need to import module first

```
jest.mock("stripe", () => {
 return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        subscriptions: {
          update: () => updateMock(),
        },
      };
    }),
  };
});
```

update is what you want to mock

Comment: i think this one is good

Comment: you can ask me if you need more explaination